# How can I identify the creator of an entry in a 'edited' collaborative list?

Tags: foursquare

It doesn't look like the response contains a 'user' object for items and there is nothing in the implementation about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a collaborative list, the creator of an item is by default the creator of a list. So if you don't see a user item associated with an item, it as created by the list creator. Items added by a friend will contain the user object for that friend.